# Debug the SpriteSheet-Unpacker cocos2d project - Closed

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

[Solved] Guys, I found another tool on Mac app store named Plist Extractor that can help me do this. Thank you guys so so much!

I found [this project](https://github.com/gongpengjun/SpriteSheet-Unpacker) on GitHub. It is a utility to unpack cocos2D sprite sheet used by cocos2d engine. After try reading and debugging this project, I cannot found any errors but it does not work as I expect. Particularly, it always generate blank images from sprite frame and save it to disk. So anyone please help me debug it. I also attach a sprite sheet for you guys to test.

[Link to sprite sheet.](http://www.mediafire.com/download/nevrzn4cbk2r4kn/sprite_sheet.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Try [This SpriteSheetUnPacker](https://app.box.com/s/6nkjxe91lnsd7gwenv5l9g8byctyubxr) its working with your sprite sheet.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. But I have found a tool on Mac app store named Plist Extractor that help me solve this problem. Anyway, thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#import "ExtractImagesFromTP.h"

[ExtractImagesFromTP createImagesFromTPPlist:@"sprite_sheet.plist"];
```

ExtractImagesFromTP Class

.h

```
@interface ExtractImagesFromTP : NSObject

+ (void)createImagesFromTPPlist:(NSString *)plist;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation ExtractImagesFromTP

+ (NSDictionary *)getAllFrameFromPlist:(NSString *)plistFile
{
    NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: plistFile];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return [dictionary objectForKey: @"frames"];
}

+ (void)createPngFromSprite:(CCSprite *)sprite fileName:(NSString *)fileName
{
    sprite.position = ccpMult(ccpFromSize(sprite.contentSize), 0.5);
    [CCDirector sharedDirector].nextDeltaTimeZero = YES;
    CCRenderTexture* render = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:sprite.contentSize.width height:sprite.contentSize.height];
    [render begin];
    [sprite visit];
    [render end];
    NSLog(@"Texture Name: %@", fileName);
    [render saveToFile:fileName format:CCRenderTextureImageFormatPNG];
}

+ (void)createImagesFromTPPlist:(NSString *)plist
{
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile: plist];
    NSDictionary *frameNames = [self getAllFrameFromPlist: plist];

    for (NSString *frameName in frameNames)
    {
        CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:frameName];
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame: frame];
        [self createPngFromSprite:sprite fileName:frameName];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. But I have found a tool on Mac app store named Plist Extractor that help me solve this problem. Anyway, thank you so so much!